# Dont replying another tweet, using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have problem, that this code, tweeting only replyMessage, without replying

```
            String replyMessage="@Pravdyk1"; 
            ResponseList<Status> list = twitter.getUserTimeline(3015573621l);
            Status st = list.get(0);
            //twitter.retweetStatus(st.getId());

            StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(replyMessage);
            statusUpdate.setInReplyToStatusId(st.getId());
            twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
```

I cant find resolving

Comment: do you want to send reply with this api ? can you show the error trace that you have please.

Comment: @jeorfevre, thank you, i have found solving)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with message of reply Status. I had to use `"@" + st.getUser().getScreenName()` combination